# Php unit тесты, как вытащить информацию из метода?

Tags: php, phpunit

Есть метод

```
 public function testUser(){
      $res = $this->client->post('/urk/scanUser/', array(
           "json" => array(
                'val' => '12345'
           )
      ));
      $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
 }
```

И второй метод

```
public function testSave(){
}
```

Как мне вытащить данные "val", которые были переданные в метод `testUser`, чтобы использовать в методе `testSave`?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `@depends`. Пример из [документации phpunit](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-examples-stacktest2-php):

```php
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class StackTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testEmpty()
    {
        $stack = [];
        $this->assertEmpty($stack);

        return $stack;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testEmpty
     */
    public function testPush(array $stack)
    {
        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertSame('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertNotEmpty($stack);

        return $stack;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testPush
     */
    public function testPop(array $stack)
    {
        $this->assertSame('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEmpty($stack);
    }
}
```

В примере методы выполняются в фиксированной последовательности, данные из предыдущего метода передаются в следующий для продолжения обработки.